# Mathematical Logic: Having trouble understanding this inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So here I wanted for fun to infer that: $$(\lvert a\rvert<\varepsilon) \rightarrow (a > -\varepsilon)
\land (a < \varepsilon)$$

In other words, if it is true that the absolute value of $a$ is less than $\varepsilon$, then $a$ is in between $-\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$.

So I started by the definition of $\lvert a \rvert$. Which says that:
$$if\; a > 0 \; then \; \lvert a\rvert=a$$
$$if\; a < 0 \; then \; \lvert a\rvert=-a$$

Which I know them to be true (by definition). So then I do the following logical steps:
$$suppose\;\lvert a\rvert<\varepsilon$$
$$a>0 \rightarrow \;a<\varepsilon$$
$$a<0 \rightarrow \;-a<\varepsilon$$

from here I am literally stuck. I do not know how to infer/conclude that $a > -\varepsilon 
\land a < \varepsilon $.

Where I get confused is in here: If I suppose that $a$ is greater than $0$, then I get that $a<\varepsilon$. If I also suppose that $a$ is less than $0$, then I get $-a<\varepsilon$ or $a>-\varepsilon$.

But how can $a$ be both positive and negative? In other words how can this statement: $a>0\,\land\;a<0$ be true?

I want them to be both true so that through modus ponens I infer $a > -\varepsilon 
\land a < \varepsilon $.

So long story short, I'd like to see this proof done by only involving logical steps.

Comment: I think brackets would help legibility here. In fact, I'll edit them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a < b$ and $r > 0$, then $ar < br.$

If $a < b$ and $r < 0$, then $ar > br$.

In other words, the rule is that when you multiply the inequality by a negative number, you must reverse the direction of the inequality.

So, $-a < \epsilon \implies (a) = [(-a) \times (-1)] > [\epsilon \times (-1)] = -\epsilon.$

Therefore, under the premises that

- $a < 0$
- $|a| < \epsilon$,

you can conclude that $a > -\epsilon.$  Combining this with the premise that $a < 0$, you have that then $-\epsilon < a < 0.$

Comment: How can it be true that $If\,a<b\,and\,r>0,\,then\,ar>br$?? Shouldn't it be
$If\,a<b\,and\,r>0,\,then\,ar<br$ ?

Comment: @gmmk : +1 : good catch; was typo(s) on my part.  Answer edited.

Comment: Also I don't want to show that $-\varepsilon<a<0$, but that: $-\varepsilon<a<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @gmmk  I intentionally truncated my answer to dovetail with the work that you had already posted.  There are $(3)$ possibilities: either $~a < 0, ~a = 0,~$ or $~a > 0.$  $a = 0$ is clearly a satisfying value.  Your posting already showed that if $a > 0,$ that $a < \epsilon.$  My work explains why, if $a < 0$, that $a > - \epsilon.$  Putting this all together, the three mutually exclusive subsets of satisfying values for $(a)$ are $$-\epsilon < a < 0 ~~~\text{or}~~~ ~a = 0 ~~~\text{or}~~~ 0 < a < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Though I am having troubles to get exaclty to this this statement: $-\varepsilon<a<\varepsilon \,$ from the set of premises. Now I've worked it out by following your ideas, and I get what you mean and what's going on under the scenes. By I do not know how I can formally convert those 'or's' in 'and's' and conclude EXACLTY this statement $-\varepsilon<a\,\land\,a<\varepsilon \,$.

Comment: In other words, instead of concluding $-\varepsilon<a<0$ or $a=0$ or $0<a<\varepsilon\;$ I want to conclude exactly this statement: $-\varepsilon < a\land a<\varepsilon$

Comment: @gmmk  Let $S_1$ denote the set $\{a~: ~-\epsilon < a < 0\}.$ Let $S_2$ denote the set $\{a~: ~a=0\}.$  Let $S_3$ denote the set $\{a ~: 0 < a < \epsilon\}.$  Let $T$ denote the set $\{a~: -\epsilon < a < \epsilon\}.$  You want to prove that $$S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 = T.$$  This is routine.  When you have two sets $A$ and $B$, and you want to prove that $A = B$, you simply have to prove two things: [1] $A \subseteq B.$ [2] $B \subseteq A.$  In general, you prove that $A \subseteq B$ by assuming that $x$ is an element in $A$ and deducing that this implies that $x$ must be an element of $B$.

Comment: Alright. So if set theory didn't exist, how would I have approached to the same conclusion? (By the way I know what you're talking about, I studied all of this and so on). Just wanted to use pure logic. But it helped.

Comment: @gmmk From a formal perspective, you can **not** attack the problem without Set theory, because you have to consider the cases of $~a < 0, a = 0,~$ and $~a > 0~$ separately.  This is because of how the absolute value function is defined.  So, you can not avoid having $(3)$ mutually exclusive sets that you have to take the union of.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As long as $\varepsilon \geq 0$, we can square both sides of the proposed inequality which holds an equivalent transformation. Having said that, we can reach the desired result:
\begin{align*}
|a| < \varepsilon & \Longleftrightarrow |a|^{2} \leq \varepsilon^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |a|^{2} - \varepsilon^{2} \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} - \varepsilon^{2} \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a - \varepsilon)(a + \varepsilon)\leq 0
\end{align*}
The last inequality is equivalent to the following collection of systems of inequalities:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
a - \varepsilon \geq 0\\\\
a + \varepsilon \leq 0
\end{cases}\quad\vee\quad
\begin{cases}
a - \varepsilon \leq 0\\\\
a + \varepsilon \geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes this is totally useful. But I wanted to show the result only from the definition of the absolute value function.

Answer (score 0):

As you've observed, if $a > 0$, $a < \epsilon$ and if $a < 0$, $a > -\epsilon$. Now $\epsilon > 0$ (you haven't said this explicitly, but it's implicitly stated in the inequality $|a| < \epsilon$), so the following statements are also true:

1. If $a < 0$, $a < \epsilon$
2. If $a > 0$, $a > -\epsilon$
3. If $a = 0$, $-\epsilon < a < \epsilon$

So, *regardless of whether $a$ is positive, negative, or $0$,* $-\epsilon < a < \epsilon$.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in statement 1 and 2. If $a<0,\,a>-\varepsilon$ and If $a>0,\,a<\varepsilon$

Comment: @gmmk user's point is that both are true, which is what you want to prove

Comment: Ok but how can I conclude this result without using words like 'regardless of', and only through a logical sounding argument? I just want to arrive to this statement $-\varepsilon<a<\varepsilon \,$ from the set of premises in a real premise -> conclusion way and as much formal as possible.